# How to also vertically align horizontally aligned image and text **while allowing page-breaks**?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, page-breaking, plain-tex, vertical-spacing

*This question is not asking for snippets of code.

It is asking for describing general practices with words.*

In plain TeX I'd like to place an image/a rectangular box at the left of some piece of text which gets processed in horizontal mode.

The upper boundary line of the rectangtular box containing the image should vertically be aligned with the boundary line denoting the height of the first line of the text. (That height is not the height of a `\strutbox` but depends on the content of that first line. It might be the cap-height, it might be the x-height or the sum of x-height and ascender of some letter, or whatever.)

Horizontally there should be a gap of about 1/3 inch between the right boundary line of the box containing the image and the left margin of the lines of text.

In any case image and text must not stick into the margins of the document.

So the width of the text should be the width of a normal line of text decreased by the width of the horizontal gap (1/3 inch) and decreased by the width of the image.

In case the text takes more vertical space than the image page-breaking may occur with lines of text which without page-breaking would vertically end up below the lower boundary line of the rectangular box containing the image.

In case the text takes less vertical space than the image, there should be a vertical gap below the text whose length is hight of image + depth of image - height of text - depth of text.

By now I consider the following approach:

Put image and horizontal gap into a horizontal box. Let's call that the `imagebox`.

Measure the width of the imagebox.

Put the text into a `\vtop` whose `\topskip` is 0pt and whose `\hsize` equals the difference of the width of the imagebox and the width of a regular line of text.
Let's call that box the "intermediate textbox".

Assign the imagebox a new depth: Height of the imagebox + depth of the imagebox - height of the intermediate textbox.
Assign the imagebox a new height: The heigt of the "intermediate textbox".

- Case 1: In case the textbox is vertically larger than the imagebox:

  Create a "surrounding `\vbox`" whose `\hsize` equals the difference of the width of the imagebox and the width of a regular line of text and whose `\leftskip` equals the width of the imagebox and whose first line begins with an `\llap` (taking `\parindent` into account) holding an "inner `\vbox`" with no `\topskip`, containing the imagebox and negative (upwards) vertical skip whose length equals the depth of the imagebox. That `\llap` is followed by the text. `\unvbox` the surrounding `\vbox`.
- Case 2: In case the textbox is vertically smaller than the imagebox:

  Create a "surrounding `\vbox`" whose `\hsize` equals the width of the imagebox and which as first/only line contains the imagebox and whose first line as `\rlap` contains an "inner `\vbox`" with the "intermediate textbox" followed by a negative (upwards) vertical skip whose length equals the depth of the intermediate textbox".

Questions:

Ad Case 1: How can it be ensured that the imagebox will not stick into the margin at the bottom? Is it sufficient to have the `\llap` within the "surrounding `\vbox`" followed by a vertical positive (downwards) skip whose length equals the depth of the imagebox, followed by significant decrease of penalty, followed by a negative (upwards) vertical skip whose length also equals the depth of the imagebox?

Ad Case 2: Both the "surrounding `\vbox`" and the "inner `\vbox`" are not `\unvbox`ed. How do you make sure that vertical glue at the top af these vertical boxes is combined with the vertical glue atop of the "surrounding `\vbox`" as if the "surrounding `\vbox`" and "inner `\vbox`" were not there?

Comment: Ad Case 1: As page-breaking can only occur in (non-internal) vertical mode, you probably can switch to vertical-mode, then check if you switched to non-internal vertical mode and if in (non-internal) vertical mode do calculations with `\pagegoal`, `\pagetotal` and the height of your "imagebox" for finding out if the image still fits on the page. If not, do a `\break` in order to ensure the image to go on the next page...  By the way: What about the case of the "intermediate textbox" (`\vtop`) due to large font having a larger height than the image? ;-) Sorry, I couldn't resist asking this. ;-)

Comment: I might place the image into a box, measure it and do the text with `\hangindent`/`\hangafter` or  `\parshape`, the first line of the text having the image as an `\llap`.